# p:selectOneMenu: Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: java, string, jsf, primefaces, converters

xhtml:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="tipo" value="#{chamadoBean.chamado.tipoChamado}" effect="drop" style="width:180px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tipo de Chamado" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{chamadoBean.tipoChamado}" var="tipo" itemValue="#{tipo}" itemLabel="#{tipo}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

bean:

```java
public List<String> getTipoChamado() {
    if (this.tipoChamado == null) {
        this.tipoChamado = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.tipoChamado.add("Reclamação");
        this.tipoChamado.add("Sugestão");
    }
    return tipoChamado;
}
```

button:

```html
<h:commandButton action="#{chamadoBean.salvar}" value="Abrir Chamado" />
```

> error: Validation Error: Value is not valid

When I use the `p:commandButton` from PrimeFaces, then it works, but it don't redirect the page. When I put `ajax="false"` in order to redirect, then I get the same error again.

Comment: What's `chamadoBean.salvar` ?

Comment: @Bhesh: literally `callBean.save`.

Comment: @caematos: The `<p:commandButton>` **should** have the same problem. When you said "it works", don't you *actually* mean "I don't see any error" or do you really mean "The action method is invoked"?

Comment: it works! it saves perfect in mysql! but dont redirects the page. Also, when I use p:commandButton ajax="false" property the error comes again. weird

Comment: Weird indeed, I can't reproduce your problem based on the code given so far. There must be more into the view which is disturbing the action. I only can't think of any possible causes. The error at least suggests that `#{chamadoBean.tipoChamado}` has somehow been changed during the submit.

Comment: there is another way to do that ? i tryed a list of selectitems but give me: javax.faces.model.SelectItem cannot be cast to java.lang.String :(

Comment: @BalusC maybe I can use a custom converter? I tryed but didnt worked:

Comment: You don't need a `List<SelectItem>` nor a `Converter` for a simple `List<String>`. I suggest you to create a blank playground page, copy the relevant code in smallest possible form to there and then test it on that page. If it works, then I'd try gradually extending the page and the bean until you get the same setup as the original page. On every step, test it until the problem reappears again.

Comment: I think that so... im really pissed off about it

Comment: Is chamado.tipoChamado really a type of String?

Comment: @BalusC i thought chamadoBean.chamado.tipoChamado should be a String while the selectitems (chamadoBean.tipoChamado) are a List of String?We are choosing one value from a list,right?

Comment: Oh, the `chamadoBean.chamado.tipoChamado`. Look like so, the `p:commandButton` would otherwise also have failed.

Comment: @BalusC , @sogukk Chamado class:     `@Column(name = "tipo_chamado")
     private String tipoChamado;`

Comment: @BalusC nice! it was an encoding problem. `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>` resolved. thanx!!

Comment: @caematos +1 for stumping BalusC, even though he did provide help in finding the solution

Comment: sorry but what is stumping ? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an encoding problem. `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>` resolved.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that the web server was forcing the default local enconding in the processing cycle. I had to change the webserver configuration file to force the use of the UTF-8 encoding.

In my case, I had to add the glassfish-web.xml file to my project and add the line

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```